# How to find the weight of the weighted least squares regression analysis?

Tags: regression, heteroscedasticity, weights

As the title, I am having trouble to the find weight at the weighted least squares estimation.

I found that some people use weights like

```r
wts <- 1/fitted(lm(abs(residuals(regmodel.1)) ~ x))^2
```

or

```r
wts <- 1/fitted(lm(y~x))
```

or

```r
wts <- 1/fitted(lm(y~x))^2
```

Where the 3 `wts` come from?

How can I find the weights?

Comment: Weights are usually related to statistical uncertainty. For example, if you are very uncertain of the value for a data point in the regression, the weight for that data point is small. If you are very certain of a data point's value then the weight is large. If you do not have this information, which is usually the case, the weights are all implicitly 1.0 in a standard unweighted regression.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Why not turn your comment into an answer? Further elaboration would be nice, but it more or less addresses the question as is.

Comment: sure - see below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those weights ($w_i$ that are based on the predicted values $\hat{y}_i$) relate to [quasi-likelihood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-likelihood) estimates for generalized linear models (GLM). In those quasi-likelihood cases you take the freedom (at the cost of an exact likelihood computation) to  *only* express the relation between the mean and variance, rather than fully specifying the specific error distribution.

E.g. for Poisson regression or binomial regression the mean and variance are implicitly equal, $\mu = V$, which is a too strong restriction when the model for the errors is not exactly Poisson or Binomial (for instance it can be, instead, some over-dispersed case of the Poisson or Binomial distribution). With quasi models you do not 'care' about the (exact) distribution and just define explicitly $\mu = c V$ (that multiplicative factor makes it less restrictive) and pretend solving a real likelihood function as if it was for an exactly known distribution.

By adjusting weights according to some function of the (predicted) outcome $w_i = 1/f(\hat{y}_i)$ you are correcting hetero-scedasticity like using a relation between the mean and variance $V \propto f(\mu)$, but without knowing the exact distribution.

**The second case** $w_i = 1/\hat{y}_i$ you might use if you expect/assume (overdispersed) Poisson, Binomial, Chi-squared (and there's possible more) error distributions (which have a linear relation $\mu = c V$ between mean and variance).

**The third case** $w_i = (1/\hat{y}_i)^2$ you might use for (overdispersed) exponentially distributed errors. (which have a quadratic relation $\mu = c V^2$ between mean and variance).

**The first case**, which seems to use some linear function of the absolute residuals, allows a much more flexible, approximation and is (I guess) used on an ad-hoc basis for more 'stranger' distributions.

You could see it as *approximating* the error distribution by a Gaussian distribution with $\epsilon_i \sim N(0,f(Y_i))$

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments: Weights are usually related to statistical uncertainty. For example, if you are very uncertain of the value for a data point in the regression, the weight for that data point is small. If you are very certain of a data point's value then the weight is large. If you do not have this information, which is usually the case, the weights are all implicitly 1.0 in a standard unweighted regression.